# Stack overflow calling Spring authenticationManager.authenticate

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security, jwt

I started with a spring boot starter project version 2.3.5, but when I call `authenticationManager.authenticate` I get a stack overflow error.

```
java.lang.StackOverflowError: null
    at ch.qos.logback.classic.Logger.callTurboFilters(Logger.java:751) ~[logback-classic-1.2.3.jar:na]
    at ch.qos.logback.classic.Logger.isDebugEnabled(Logger.java:469) ~[logback-classic-1.2.3.jar:na]
    at ch.qos.logback.classic.Logger.isDebugEnabled(Logger.java:465) ~[logback-classic-1.2.3.jar:na]
    at org.apache.commons.logging.LogAdapter$Slf4jLog.isDebugEnabled(LogAdapter.java:310) ~[spring-jcl-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager.authenticate(ProviderManager.java:186) ~[spring-security-core-5.3.5.RELEASE.jar:5.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter$AuthenticationManagerDelegator.authenticate(WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.java:524) ~[spring-security-config-5.3.5.RELEASE.jar:5.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager.authenticate(ProviderManager.java:219) ~[spring-security-core-5.3.5.RELEASE.jar:5.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter$AuthenticationManagerDelegator.authenticate(WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.java:524) ~[spring-security-config-5.3.5.RELEASE.jar:5.3.5.RELEASE]
```

Initially I did not use the user variable and instead created created the new `UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken` inside the `authenticationManager.authenticate` either way I get the stack overflow error. I also have tried `@PostMapping` instead of `@RequestMapping` and Method. All of these cause the same failure.
I get the printline that says I am "in /Authenticate" with the following.

```
2020-11-09 16:20:32.141 DEBUG 10456 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped to io.javabrains.springsecurityjwt.HelloResource#createAuthenticationToken(AuthenticationRequest)
2020-11-09 16:20:32.188 DEBUG 10456 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] m.m.a.RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor : Read "application/json;charset=UTF-8" to [io.javabrains.springsecurityjwt.models.AuthenticationRequest@758a32c5]
in /Authenticate
2020-11-09 16:20:32.197 DEBUG 10456 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Failed to complete request: org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Handler dispatch failed; nested exception is java.lang.StackOverflowError
2020-11-09 16:20:32.201 ERROR 10456 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Handler dispatch failed; nested exception is java.lang.StackOverflowError] with root cause
```

Here is the full code of the Class
Thank you for any info or things I should try!

```
package io.javabrains.springsecurityjwt;

import io.javabrains.springsecurityjwt.models.AuthenticationRequest;
import io.javabrains.springsecurityjwt.models.AuthenticationResponse;
import io.javabrains.springsecurityjwt.services.MyUserDetailsService;
import io.javabrains.springsecurityjwt.util.JwtUtil;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.BadCredentialsException;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
public class HelloResource {

    @Autowired
    private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

    @Autowired
    private MyUserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @Autowired
    private JwtUtil jwtTokenUtil;

    @RequestMapping( "/hello")
    public String hello() {
        return "Hello World";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/authenticate", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ResponseEntity<?> createAuthenticationToken(@RequestBody AuthenticationRequest authenticationRequest) throws Exception {
        UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken user = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(authenticationRequest.getUsername(), authenticationRequest.getPassword());
        System.out.println("in /Authenticate");
        try {
            authenticationManager.authenticate(
                    user
//                  new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(authenticationRequest.getUsername(), authenticationRequest.getPassword())
            );
            System.out.println("in Try in /Authenticate");
        } catch (BadCredentialsException e) {
            throw new Exception("Incorrect Username or Password", e);
        }
        System.out.println("outside the try catch");

        final UserDetails userDetails = userDetailsService
                .loadUserByUsername(authenticationRequest.getUsername());
        final String jwt = jwtTokenUtil.generateToken(userDetails);

        return ResponseEntity.ok(new AuthenticationResponse(jwt));

    }
}
```

Comment: You showed us the wrong class. You need to show us your security configuration, e.g. your subclass of `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter`, and security-related values in `application.properties`.

Comment: Thank you for your response! Although Im a little confused. Im not using WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter, and application.properties only has debug=true; in it.